# Python Playwright, Select last item question

Tags: python, automation, playwright

I need to automate grabbing something from first column and something from last column.

The trouble relays that all of the items have the same area to click

```
<div _ngcontent-fse-c5="" class="battle-status ng-star-inserted" data-test-id="selectForBattleButton"> Select for battle </div>
```

they are nested on

```
<app-cat-card _ngcontent-fse-c3="" _nghost-fse-c5="" ng-reflect-cat="[object Object]" ng-reflect-did-cat-fight="false" ng-reflect-selectable="true" ng-reflect-should-show-success-overlay="false" ng-reflect-should-show-failure-overlay="false" data-test-id="cat_1" class="ng-star-inserted"><div _ngcontent-fse-c5="" data-test-id="catCard" class="cat-card"><img _ngcontent-fse-c5="" class="cat-avatar" src="https://robohash.org/flexible-stuart.png"><div _ngcontent-fse-c5="" class="cat-details"><p _ngcontent-fse-c5="" class="cat-name">Flexible Stuart</p><p _ngcontent-fse-c5=""><b _ngcontent-fse-c5="">Power move:</b> Searching Swan <br _ngcontent-fse-c5=""><b _ngcontent-fse-c5="">Experience level:</b> 10 </p><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><div _ngcontent-fse-c5="" class="ng-star-inserted"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><div _ngcontent-fse-c5="" class="battle-status ng-star-inserted" data-test-id="selectForBattleButton"> Select for battle </div><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--></div><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--></div></div></app-cat-card>
```

It is my first time using **playwright** and could use a clue or assistance.

I have tried

```
page.click("text=Select for Battle ")
```

to click the first but if i do it again the second one gets clicked and if i do it again the first is selected again.

Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try following `css selector` to identify the element and then click the item.

```
await page.click("[data-test-id='selectForBattleButton']");
```